# Find line location where file is being required from

Tags: node.js, require

I am running some code where it's requiring a file that loads a server two times in a row (which throws a BIND error), I'm logging `require.main` from the required file and seeing that it's being called from my `app.js` file twice, but I can't see which lines it's being required one (if I could I could remove one and fix the error).

Is there any way to see the line of code as well?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, it's hard to definitively say where the problem is. However, it sounds like you quite simply are calling the file twice. I recommend throwing in some console.logs to see where things break and identify which line is extra. Also a solid ctrl-f could do the trick.